# Why matlab does not show multi band image correctly

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am new in matlab.I have a multi-band composite landsat image that i can read easily in arcgis, envi or other remote sensing software and i can play with the band combination too in those software but when i try to load this multi-band composite landsatimage in matlab 2016. I tried `imfinfo`tool to find image metadata and used those metadata in `multibandread` command and tried changing `bil`, `bip` `bsq` but all went in vain.

matlab code-

```
compositeimage ='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Image\Clip_Composite_LT51360451997307BKT00_B11.tif';
iminfo = imfinfo(compositeimage);
truecolor = multibandread(compositeimage, [1281, 620, 6], 'uint8=>uint8', ...
                          8,  'bip', 'ieee-le', {'Band','Direct',[4 3 2]});
imshow(truecolor);
```

imfinfo tool result as below-

[image: infi]

matlab output-

[image: matlab output]

Original file as looks in arcgis/envi-

[image: original]

Comment: IIRC, `PlanarConfiguration:Chunky` corresponds to `bip` so you have that correct.

Comment: This question may fit better on [gis.stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They are `uint16` not `uint8` !!!

Comment: @MarkSetchell landsat has radiometric resolution of 8bit- BTW `uint16` did not help either.

Comment: Your file has 16 bits per sample if you do the maths with the number of rows * number of columns * 6 samples * 2 bytes per sample and that comes to the filesize, so regardless of Landsat's resolution, the file is storing uint16 data.